# Typescript: Module X has no exported member Y

Tags: typescript

EDIT/NOTE, found problem: This was happening when an import above it was silently failing because I had not installed a certain @types/package.

I'm getting this baffling error from Typescript:

```
ERROR in C:\...\src\components\App.tsx(26,10)
      TS2614: Module '"../.../src/components/PriceCharting"' has no exported member 'PriceChart'. 
Did you mean to use 'import PriceChart from "../.../src/components/PriceCharting"' instead?
```

I'm exporting like

```
export const PriceChart = () => ...
```

and I'm importing like

```
import { PriceChart } from "./PriceCharting";
```

Has anyone experienced this problem?

**Workaround**: if I export instead like

```
export default PriceChart;
```

and import like

```
import PriceChart from "./PriceCharting";
```

Then it works!

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work and I believe I found the problem.  Above the import I had another import that must caused the problem:

import {
  LineChart,
  ...
} from "recharts";

I believe this was failing because I did not add @types/recharts, but I was getting that other error instead for some reason.